# Django Basics myapp mapping in myproject "myapp" is not defined

Tags: django

I am learning django, and have ran `python manage.py startapp myapp` which created the following folder structure:

```
myapp/
   __init__.py
   admin.py
   models.py
   tests.py
   views.py
```

I also added `myapp` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'myapp',
)
```

then I ran `python manage.py migrate` and `python manage.py createsuperuser` to create super user

I have also created views of myapp :

```
"from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
   text = """<h1>welcome to my app !</h1>"""
   return HttpResponse(text)
"
```

Finally, here's the URL mapping:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^admin', include(admin.site.urls)),
   url(r'^hello/', 'myapp.views.hello', name = 'hello'),
)
```

When ran, it throws an error stating that "myapp" is not defined. And I am not able to access admin page at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin

How can I solve this error and get my application to work?

Comment: If you just started with Django, I'd advise to stick the current (new) conventions, and make `patterns` a list: `patterns = [url(...), url(...)]`.

Comment: You may want to carefully check the directory where myapp is located, and play around chaing 'myapp' to 'myproject.myapp' in the INSTALLED_APPS. Since you're not listing your full directory structure, it's a bit hard to guess what precisely might be wrong.

Comment: Post the exact error message

Answer (score 0):

Possibly `myapp` is not included in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `setting.py`. I suppose you are following [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_url_mapping.htm) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your url mapping:

```
from myapp import views
```