# Django URL mapping - NameError: name X is not defined

Tags: django

[A similar question was asked, but not marked as answered, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823570/django-basics-myapp-mapping-in-myproject-myapp-is-not-defined). I considered continuing that thread but the website told me I'm only supposed to post an answer, so it seems I have to start a new topic.] I'm trying to follow [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_url_mapping.htm) tutorial and I'm having problems with the URL mapping. Specifically with the part described as "So best practice is to create an “url.py” per application and to include it in our main projects url.py file". The relevant, I hope, part of the folder structure, which arose by following steps of the tutorial to the letter (if possible; usage of the 'patterns' module was impossible for example) and using Django 1.10 is the following:

```
myproject/
  myapp/
    urls.py
    views.py
  myproject/
    urls.py
```

The myproject/urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from myapp.views import hello

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^myapp/', include(myapp.urls)),
]
```

The myapp/urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^hello/', myapp.views.hello),
]
```

The myapp/views.py is as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def hello(request):
   return render(request, "hello.html", {})
```

However, running 'python manage.py runserver' results in the following error:

```
url(r'^myapp/', include(myapp.urls)),
NameError: name 'myapp' is not defined
```

INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py contains 'myapp'.

I'd be greatful for any tips on how to deal with the NameError! [Or any tips whatsoever that anyone might consider to be helpful!]

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Django 1.10 seems to be the "latest official version" according to the Django website. I thought it'be reasonable to install it. I don't know what 'class based views' are. I will investigate. But are you confident this is the root of the NameError?

Comment: [The tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_url_mapping.htm) you linked to is written for Django 1.6 or earlier (`admin.autodiscover()` has not been required since Django 1.7) . A lot has changed since then, so I wouldn't recommend following it. The [official Django 1.10 tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/) shows you how to create an app with a url config which will work with Django 1.10.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will move to the new tutorial.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have the `NameError` because you are referencing `myapp` in `myproject/urls.py` but haven't imported it.

The typical approach in Django is to use a string with include, which means that the import is not required.

```
url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
```

Since you have move the `hello` URL pattern into `myapp/urls.py`, you can remove `from myapp.views import hello` from `myproject/urls.py`.

Once you've made that change, you will get another `NameError` in `myapp/urls.py`. In this case, a common approach is to use a relative import for the app's views.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^hello/$', views.hello),
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: I also ran into this issue upgrading to Django 2.0+ and the relative . import fixed my issue for an installed app view. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have imported following modules to `urls.py`.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
```

Answer (score 2):

in django 2.0
use these

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [


    path('',views.index, name="index"),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

your app URL has to be a string
so, here is how the code should look like.

from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from myapp.views import hello

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

also, note that from python 2 upward the regular expression is not needed.
change URL to path
from django.conf.URLs import include path

from Django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from myapp.views import hello

```
urlpatterns = [
path('^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
path('^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django 2.1.7 here is the default  urls .py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

so we need to add this line as well
    from django.conf.urls import url

Answer (score 0):

I have followed @Alasdair answers

> You have the NameError because you are referencing myapp in myproject/urls.py but haven't imported it.
>
> The typical approach in Django is to use a string with include, which
> means that the import is not required.

Unfortunately, it didn't work out(I still got the `name X is not defined` error). Here is how I do it.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import url
from article import urls as article_users
from article import urls as user_urls 

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/article/', include(article_users)),
    path('api/user/', include(user_urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using the URL command be sure to first import the url from the module Urls. Then try using the runserver.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
```